# `[(ngModel)]` vs `[(value)]`

Tags: angular

What is the difference between

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name">
```

and

```
<input [(value)]="name">
```

They appear to do the same thing.

The angular docs are using **NgModel** but they also say that they replace all the angular1 directives with the "boxed banana" [()]. So why is **NgModel** still around?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

- `ngModel` is a directive that allows your input to participate in a form (but works also without a form)
- `value` is a property you can bind a value to with `[value]="name"` while `(valueChange)="..."` doesn't work, because the `<input>` element doesn't have an `@Output() valueChange;` therefore `[(value)]="..."` is invalid.

`[(ngModel)]="name"` is the shorthand for `[ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="name = $event"` as is `[(value)]="name"` for `[value]="name" (valueChange)="name = $event"`

Comment: you mean we cant catch ValueChanged(VALUE) when using [(value)]="VARIABLE" ?

Comment: That's right, because there is no `valueChange` event. There is a `value` property and a `change` or `input` event, depending on the input element, so you would need to use `[value]="value" (change)="value = $event"` (or `input` instead of `change`) to get a similar result.