# Input value is not working inside a modal

Tags: angular

I want to put a value inside an input.

this is what I did:

```
<input [value]="example" [(ngModel)]="phaseToUpdate.phaseName" type='text' >
```

and usually it's working 
but I think it is not working right now because this input is inside a modal.

any suggestions what do to ?

Comment: <input type="text" [(value)]='example'> use it like this

Comment: still not working

Comment: <input type='text'  [ngModel]="phaseToUpdate?.phaseName"  >

Comment: is your modal template inside component class ?? If not that is the reason as your component variable is not accessible outside...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind using the two way data binding

```
<input type="text" id="example" [(ngModel)]="example">
    <span class="e">{{example}}</span>
```

Comment: well i'm using the ngModel for catching the value the user enters the input
so my input basiclly looks like that:
<input [value]="example" [(ngModel)]="phaseToUpdate.phaseName" type='text' >

Comment: i think you need to go through this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699705/ngmodel-vs-value

Comment: you cant have both value and ngmodel on the same element, if you have, ngmodel would overwrite that

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below, it will

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="What's your name?">
```