# Input's value changes but not rendered in DOM

Tags: angular

I'm trying to solve this thing I've got in my app:

I've a simple number input (not form, just a dummy input). I've created a "validation" inside my component's class. The problem is that if I change the input's value in code, first time the validator changes the value, but the second or more time the change isn't reflected in DOM. Here is a stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpnt83).

In my example app I have a really simple set-up:

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="number" [value]="inputValue" (change)="onInputChange($event.target.value)">
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public inputValue: number = 0;

  public onInputChange(event: number | string): void {
    const val = Number(event);
    if (val > 100) {
      this.inputValue = 100;
    }
  }
}
```

Steps:

- change the value to 200 and press enter
- since is larger than 100 the validator changes the input value to 100
- change the value to 200 again and press enter
- the value in DOM stays 200 instead of 100

My guess here is, that since second time the value of `inputValue` doesn't changes, the DOM doesn't got re-rendered. But if I trigger change detection manually, nothing happens.

Any idea guys?

Comment: Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[value]` [Read more](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

Comment: Thanks it works that way. I'm curious if I can do it just with [value]?

Comment: Sorry! you can't [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42699787/11719787)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `ngModel`, because you don't want to load the `FormsModule`, you can use the target input straight:

```
public onInputChange(input: HTMLInputElement): void {
  const val = Number(input.value);
  if (val > 100) {
    this.inputValue = 100;
    input.value = this.inputValue.toString();
  }
}
```

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2gdlj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)