# How to set fields values in Angular forms

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to set view field values when "user_details" object is populated in the .ts on the ngOnInit() execution.

This is the .ts where I'm filling the user_details object.

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  user_details = {
    name: '',
    first_surname: '',
    second_surname: '',
    age: '',
    birdth_date: '',
    location: '',
    phone: '',
    image: ''
  };
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.getProfile()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.user_details = res;
        console.log(this.user_details)
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

As you see, the object is getting correct data.

[image]

This is the form where I need to fill the fields.

```
<div class="container p-4">
    <form (submit)="updateProfile()">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-white">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user_details.name" value={{user_details.name}} name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="first_surname">First surname</label>
                  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user_details.first_surname" name="first_surname" value={{user_details.first_surname}} class="form-control" id="first_surname" placeholder="First surname">
                </div>
...
```

How can I set the values of the view fields with this object data?
I need to be displayed "user_details" fields in the view, and my view is empty.

[image]
Thanks for reading!

Comment: just want to make if i understood your question, so you want to display the vaues when user types it ? Am i right ?

Comment: Not exactly, when getProfile() function is executed it returns some user values. Those values I need to be displayed in the different fields of the form. @SijuSamson

Comment: what exactly is the problem? I've reproduced your example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-fayys8?file=app/app.component.ts) which seems to be working fine.

Comment: So you get a response when you are calling getProfile(), so you want to display it ?

Comment: Whe I call getProfile() I get an user object "user_details = {'name': ........} and this object I need to be setted in the different form fields defined in the view. @SijuSamson

Comment: It gives me the empty fields in the view. @Viqas

Comment: @Viqas edited again

Comment: also check console.log(res), is res missing values or problem in user_detial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best way is to use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), as it provides lot of features, which you may need in forms. I have tried to recreate your code in [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-breeze-7i9r3?), please have a look at it, as I was able to solve it,

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="first_surname">Name</label>
<input
  type="text"
  [(ngModel)]="user_details.name.first"
  name="first_surname"
  value="user_details.name.first"
  class="form-control"
  id="name"
  placeholder="Name"
/>
```

Comment: The problem was here: this.user_details = res['user_details'];, in a simple dictionary equality, your code helped me to solved the problem! Thanks! @Siju Samson

Comment: @adriano009 If it helped you, please give an upvote, so that other users can see it, if they also encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be in using ngModel and Value.

Refer to this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42699787/13266781) in another question for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Remove the `value` property from the input tag.

**Right answer**
Use angular forms [read here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).
After setting the from Group for your form set value for the right controller

Answer (score 0):

the way I solved that problem was by using 1st reactiveFroms. just like other answers mentioned and here is how I did it.

there are two ways your user will have their data on the component but in most cases, it will be called from the db which means a promise or an observable.

in that case. the psuedo code will look something like this.

```js
ngOnInit() {
 this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl(null,),
      lastName: new FormControl(null,),
      mobile: new FormControl(null),
    });
    
    this.YourService.getProfileInformation().subscribe((data: UserProfile) => {
    // you might want to check if your data is right and fits the form fields
      this.form.setValue({
      firstName: data.firstName,
      lastName: data.lastName,
      mobile: data.mobile
      })
    })
}
```

I believe this is the cleanest way to do that.